# In php how to create database dynamically on godaddy server

Tags: php, mysql, database, cpanel

I am using this code to create database on runtime. But it is not working. Getting error:

> No user created.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_query("CREATE USER 'xyz'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';");
mysql_query("GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'xyz'@'localhost'");
mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE locus_ag_1234");
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: mysql_connect is deprecated try using pdo or mysqli your tag is showing mysqli but you connect with mysql

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani I have updated my code from mysql to mysqli but its not working on server.

Comment: can you edit your post with the new connection ?